# GridBagLayout align textField?

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I want to shorten my text field so it doesn't stretch to to the end of my jframe so this is how it looks now:
[image]

How do control the width of the textfield so it does't streatch like that I tried setPreferedSize() and setSize() yet they didn't work??

```
@Override
        public void run() {

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Calculator");
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setSize(500, 500);

            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

            JLabel testLabel = new JLabel("Enter Score For Test 1: ");  
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 0;
            c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            c.insets = new  Insets(40, 15, 15, 0);
            panel.add(testLabel , c);


            JTextField txtField1 = new JTextField("TextField");
            c.gridx = 1;
            c.gridy = 0;
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            c.weightx = .5; 
            panel.add(txtField1 , c);
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're telling the layout that the text field must fill horizontally, so that's what it does. Replace

```
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
```

by

```
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
```

Answer (score 3):

First and foremost, get rid of this:

```
frame.setSize(500, 500);
```

Instead let your components and layout managers *size themselves* by calling `pack()` on your JFrame after filling it and before setting it visible.

Next, consider either adding an empty border around your main container, or else adding an empty JLabel to your GridBagLayout using container.

You can also give your JTextField appropriate insets to give a cushion around it.

```
c.insets = new  Insets(40, 15, 15, 40);
panel.add(txtField1, c);
```

Comment: "Next, consider either adding an empty border around your main container, or else adding an empty JLabel to your GridBagLayout using container" I don't get why I would need to do that? explain please

Comment: @babaysteps: it all depends on what you're trying to do. If you want an empty border around all components added to the panel, then give it an EmptyBorder which is similar to insets. If you want an empty column on the right, then instead add a blank JLabel in the c.gridY = 2 position. If you just want to move the right end of your JTextField in a little, then change the insets as I've shown above. I suggest that you experiment with your code and try these things out, that you go through the tutorials too.

Answer (score 2):

You can change how many columns a particular component takes up by changing  GridBagConstraints gridwidth field.

```
//this would make the next component take up 2 columns
c.gridwidth = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have a jpanel and set its dimensions and layout, then add the elements to that panel and add the panel to your jframe.

Answer (score 0):

There are different layout types that can be used depending on what you need to be done. I usually like to use Box's. They have methods that allow you to create horizontal/vertical struts, create rigid areas(this is what I usually use)

```
    Box box1 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    Box box2 = Box.createVerticalBox();

    box1.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(30,0)));
    box1.add(testLabel);
    box1.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(30,0)));
    box1.add(txtField1);
    box1.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(30,0)));

    box2.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,30)));
    box2.add(box1);
    box2.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,30)));

    JFrame.add(box2);
```

Check this link out for descriptions and how to use all the different kinds of layouts: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html